# Filter an array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of slides

```
$slide = $(".slide")
```

**Just one** of those slides also has the class "current". How can I select it **from the array**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the filter method see [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
$(".slide").filter('.current');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var $slide = $(".slide").filter('.current');
```

or simply change the selector to require both classes:

```
var $slide = $(".slide.current");
```

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed. Congratulations with the moderator status! :)

Comment: Thanks. I will mark as correct the other answer, because as i stated, I only wanted to select it FROM THE ARRAY. But still appreciate the help.